# Allow multiple rows to have same X value only if also same Y value?

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

Given a (postgres) table,

```sql
CREATE TABLE links (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    url text NOT NULL,
    owner_id bigint NOT NULL
);
```

I'd like to allow multiple rows to have the same `url` if and only if they also have the same `owner_id`.

I.e. this would be allowed:

```
 id | url | owner_id
----+-----+---------
  7 | foo |        1
  8 | bar |        1
  9 | bar |        1
```

but this would not:

```
 id | url | owner_id
----+-----+---------
  7 | foo |        1
  8 | bar |        1
  9 | bar |        2
```

Is there any way to enforce such a constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an EXCLUDE constraint.  You will need a helper extension to get the correct operators to use.

```
create extension btree_gist;
alter table links add constraint lksjdf 
    exclude using gist (url with =, owner_id with <>);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to normalize your tables.

Clearly, `url` has a many-one relationship to `owner`, so it should go in its own table.

```
CREATE TABLE owner (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE url (
    url text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    owner_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES owner (id)
);

CREATE TABLE links (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    url text NOT NULL REFERENCES url (url)
);
```

The downside of this normalized design is that you now need to join `url` to find out what the `owner_id` is.

So if you want `links` to also contain `owner_id` then you could give `url` a multi-column secondary key.

```
CREATE TABLE owner (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE url (
    url text NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    owner_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES owner (id),
    UNIQUE (owner_id, url)
);

CREATE TABLE links (
    id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    owner_id bigint NOT NULL
    url text NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id, url) REFERENCES url (owner_id, url)
);
```

This design still ensures that each `url` only has a single `owner_id`, but `links` then refers to *both* those two columns together.

You could also give the `url` a surrogate key, if you feel that `url.url` is too wide.